# How to load views on an added Devise module for a custom registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, devise

My rails 3.0.3 app uses devise gem (1.1.5) for authentication and before I wasn't using the :registerable module. I have since added that to enable users to sign up. I then implemented my own registration controller which extends Devise::RegistrationsController. Now when I visit the url /users/sign_up. I get "*Missing template error*" because rails doesn't find the registration views under *app/views*. I had generated the devise views using `rails generate devise_views` which means that my registration views are under app/views/devise/. When I copy the views to app/views/ folder it works. This doesn't seem very DRY. Is there a way of telling rails to use the views in app/views/devise?

thanks,
Kibet.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have added an additional load path config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/views/devise ) to config/application.rb which still doesn't make rails use the generated devise views.

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way to do this either...ended up just doing the same as you, moving registrations to /views.  Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a line in \config\application.rb

```
config.paths['app/views'] << "app/views/devise"
```

Comment: Thank you. A sample of a project that uses this technique: https://github.com/forker/multiversion